# BigCommerce changing order history view

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm working on a BigCommerce site. Right now if a customer goes to their order history, they can view each order, but to see what products were included in the order, they have to click into the order number. I'd like to make a way for them to be able to view all the products they've ordered in one spot, instead of having to click into each order individually. Is this possible? I'm new to Bigcommerce and since I'm not the store owner, just doing some dev work, I'm not able to post on their Q&A page.

Answer (score 0):

There's an expand button for all of the orders on a particular page, it's the little '+' at the top. This will expand all of them so you can see the products in each:

[image: + icon at the top]

Comment: That's for the shop owner view though. I'm talking about as a customer, when I log into my customer account and see what I've purchased, I see something like "Order #123456, includes 6 items" - and if I want to see what items are included, I have to click into the order number. I'd like customers to be able to see all items ordered on one page.

Answer (score 0):

Molly: are you on a Stencil theme?

If so you can do this by editing the theme.  Check out these two files:

/templates/components/account/orders-list.html (lists all orders)

/templates/components/account/order-contents.html (individual order details)

You can update orders-list.html to have info about the products ordered, using what is on order-contents as a reference.

For example, if you just wanted to add the product name and quantity:

```
{{#each orders}}
...
    <ul>
        {{#each items}}
            <li>{{quantity}} &#215; {{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
...
{{/each}}
```

... within the orders loop.

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you! I'm sorry I didn't see this sooner, but I will take a look at that.